# Tensorflow:Model.fit() InvalidArgumentError: indices[28,13] = -2147483648 is not in [0, 1193514)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
Train on 28624 samples
Epoch 1/10
   32/28624 [..............................] - ETA: 15:20

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-4679097c6578> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(X_train_indices, Y_train_OH, epochs = 10, batch_size = 32)**

InvalidArgumentError:  indices[15,2] = -2147483648 is not in [0, 1193514)
     [[node model_1/embedding_1/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-25-4679097c6578>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_6120]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node model_1/embedding_1/embedding_lookup:
 model_1/embedding_1/embedding_lookup/4992 (defined at C:\Users\shash\Anaconda3\envs\sentiment_analysis\lib\contextlib.py:81)

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

**System information**

- Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow): Yes
- OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Windows 10
- TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): Conda
- TensorFlow version (use command below): 2.1.0
- Python version: 3.6.10
- CUDA/cuDNN version: NA
- GPU model and memory: Disabled (Hardcoding TensorFlow without GPU)

**Code**

**->Embedding layer**

```
def pretrained_embedding_layer(word_to_vec_map, word_to_index):
   

    vocab_len = len(word_to_index) + 1            #1193514      
    emb_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_len,embedding_dim))
    for word, idx in word_to_index.items():
        emb_matrix[idx, :] = word_to_vec_map[word]

    # Definning a pre-trained Embedding layer
    embedding_layer = layers.Embedding(
                        vocab_len,
                        embedding_dim,
                        trainable = False
                        )

    # Build the embedding layer, it is required before setting the weights of the embedding layer. 
    embedding_layer.build((None,))
    
    # Set the weights of the embedding layer to the embedding matrix. Your layer is now pretrained.
    embedding_layer.set_weights([emb_matrix])
    
    return embedding_layer
```

**->Model**

```
def sentiment_model(input_shape, word_to_vec_map, word_to_index):


    sentence_indices =layers.Input(shape=input_shape, dtype='float32')
    
    # Create the embedding layer pretrained with GloVe Vectors
    embedding_layer = pretrained_embedding_layer(word_to_vec_map, word_to_index)
    
    # Propagate sentence_indices through your embedding layer
    # (See additional hints in the instructions).
    embeddings = embedding_layer(sentence_indices)   

    x = layers.LSTM(128)(embeddings)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    predictions = layers.Dense(2, activation="sigmoid", name="predictions")(x)
    
    # Create Model instance which converts sentence_indices into X.
    model = keras.Model(inputs=sentence_indices,outputs=predictions)   
    return model
```

```
def sentences_to_indices(X, word_to_index, max_len):

    X_indices = np.zeros((m,max_len))
    
    # Assign indices to words
    for i,sentence in enumerate(X):        
        sentence_words = sentence.lower().split()
        for j,word in enumerate(sentence_words):
            X_indices[i, j] = word_to_index[word]
    return X_indices
```

```
def get_word_embedding_dictionary():
""" creates word_to_vector, word_to_index and index_to_word dictionaries """
with open(embeding_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    words = set()
    word_to_vec_map = {}
    
    # Extracting word and its vectors
    for line in f:
        line_list = line.split()
        
        # Ignoring unresolvable words
        if len(line_list)!=embedding_dim+1:
            continue
        curr_word = line_list[0]
        words.add(curr_word)
        word_to_vec_map[curr_word] = np.array(line_list[1:], dtype=np.float64)
    
    word_to_index = {}
    index_to_word = {}
    for i,w in enumerate(sorted(words)):
        word_to_index[w] = i
        index_to_word[i] = w
return word_to_index, index_to_word, word_to_vec_map
```

```
X_train_indices = sentences_to_indices(X_train, word_to_index, max_features)
Y_train_OH = to_categorical(Y_train)
model.fit(X_train_indices, Y_train_OH, epochs = 10, batch_size = 32)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when the words are being replaced by their corresponding index. If the word wasn't found in the vocabulary/word_to_index dictionary it was being stored as **nan**.

The vocabulary is all the words present in the word embeddings (I have used GloVe twitter embeddings).

Modified function:

```
def sentences_to_indices(X, word_to_index, max_len):

X_indices = np.zeros((m,max_len))

# Assign indices to words
for i,sentence in enumerate(X):        
    sentence_words = sentence.lower().split()
    for j,word in enumerate(sentence_words):
        X_indices[i, j] = word_to_index.get(word,0)  #improvement
return X_indices
```

Though, I am not sure if words not present in word embeddings should be stored as zero.